# mvc-CollapsiblePanelExtender

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajaxcontroltoolkit, collapsiblepanelextender

hey,
I want to have CollapsiblePanelExtender  on my view and when user click on label panel should expand/collapse. Here is my code:

```
<table><tr><td> <label id="MyLabel">Text</label></td></tr><asp:Panel ID="MyPanel" runat="server"><table></table>
</asp:Panel>
    <cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="MyPanel_CollapsiblePanelExtender" 
        runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="MyPanel" ExpandControlID="MyLabel" CollapseControlID="MyLabel">
    </cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

Problem is that nothing happens when I click on my label...

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit? `<asp:Panel`? `<cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender`? In an MVC application view? I think you are mixing some concepts here. Those notions no longer exist in MVC. That's classic WebForms that you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're speaking about asp.net mvc than you can use the jQuery UI Accordion

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/